# How to calculate AVG, MIN & MAX of date interval of a column in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a table more like this

```
    +----+-------------+---------------------+
    | id |  order_id   | transaction_date    |
    +----+-------------+---------------------+
    | 1  | TEST000001  | 2018-01-01 00:00:10 |
    | 2  | TEST000002  | 2018-01-01 00:10:10 |
    | 3  | TEST000003  | 2018-01-02 03:18:01 |
    | 4  | TEST000004  | 2018-02-04 05:00:00 |
    | 5  | TEST000005  | 2018-02-10 16:00:10 |
    +----+-------------+---------------------+
```

There is datetime field named *transaction_date*, so what I want to do is doing a calculation of time interval (day interval), so that I will get an average, minimum and maximum time interval for all records I have.

Sample expectation :

```
    +------------------+------------------+------------------+
    | average_interval | minimum_interval | maximum_interval |
    +--------------------------------------------------------+
    |              2.0 |                1 |                3 |
    +------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

What I've done so far is using `LAG()` function more like the following `SELECT` script.

```
SELECT AVG(date_interval) AS average_interval,
       MIN(date_interval) AS minimum_interval,
       MAX(date_interval) AS maximum_interval
FROM (
  SELECT
    transaction_date - LAG(transaction_date)
      OVER (PARTITION BY transaction_date ORDER BY id) AS date_interval
    FROM transactions
) t;
```

But the outcome was far from my expectation, `null` result

[image]

I believe thats not a proper way to solve it, any suggestions ?

Comment: please only use text instead of images see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Use `timestampdiff()` rather than `-`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not confident about using `-` in MySQL.  Use `TIMESTAMPDIFF()`.  Your problem, however, is the `PARTITION BY` lcause:

```
SELECT AVG(date_interval) AS average_interval,
       MIN(date_interval) AS minimum_interval,
       MAX(date_interval) AS maximum_interval
FROM (SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, transaction_date,
                           LAG(transaction_date) OVER (ORDER BY transaction_date) 
                          ) AS date_interval
      FROM transactions
     ) t;
```

Comment: Ah, I see, I tried this one with a bit changes in the use of `TIMESTAMPDIFF` to `DATEDIFF` and that's do the thing, thanks.